# IIS 6 granting permission from one web app to the other

Tags: .net, sharepoint, iis

Hi & thanks for looking.

## Background

.NET 4, IIS 6, C#

I am developing an app that requests JSON from a service application staging server.  When running in localhost, I must be authenticated via my company's VPN in order for my app to call the staging server and get the JSON it needs.  This works fine.

I have just pushed a build of the application to the same server as the service application.  They both run in separate app pools.

## Problem

Now, when I access the application as it runs on the staging server, requests to the service app for JSON fail due to security.

How do I circumvent this?  I can't seem to figure out how to add permissions to the service app for my new app which doesn't require a VPN connection like when I am running on localhost.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: This is arguably not a programming question. If this is a test environment you can enable Anonymous authentication (unless your app requires information based on the AD authenticated user).

Comment: You need to add details on what specific error you're getting.  Also, what is your asp.net/web.config configuration?

Comment: @bryanmac- Thanks for your help.  I have to admit, I don't know how to trace this error.  It is simply a 500 that gets returned to the app that is making the JSON request with no further description.  Is there perhaps a common log file on the server somewhere that documents failed requests?  I am sure that I should know that but I don't.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @bryanmac:  Also, regarding web config, there is no membership provider or anything like that.  I am not using authentication.  It is a basic MVC3 app from the standard .NET MVC web app template on which I have placed some code generation tools for us developers.  It's job is to call the aforementioned other app, grab some serialized SharePoint data, and write entities to a .cs file.  This works great from localhost when VPN connected, but fails when running on the same web server as the JSON provider (different app pool).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try using JSONP like here: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/SharePoint-Online-and-External-Data-using-JSONP.aspx

Comment: Hi Ivan.  Thanks for this input, but use of jsonp will not solve my particular problem.